# Language switcher with bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, language-switching

I am trying to build a language switcher inside the navbar.

My code is the following (in `_LoginPartial.cshtml`)

```
using ( Html.BeginForm( "SetCulture", "Home", FormMethod.Post ) ) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="@selectedImgSrc" alt="@culture" />
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="language" rel="it-IT"><img src="~/assets/images/i18n/it-IT.png" alt="Italiano" /></a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#" class="language" rel="en-US"><img src="~/assets/images/i18n/en-US.png" alt="English" /></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
}
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" } )</li>
    <li>@Html.ActionLink( "Sign in", "Login", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" } )</li>
</ul>
```

`@selectedImgSrc` value is `~/assets/images/i18n/en-US.png`

`@culture value` is `en-us`

However this code produce the following result

[image: Bootstrap language switcher]

Which has a couple of problems:

- On the nav the image is not showed but only the text (en-US)
- The dropdown is too large and I dont like it. Is there any way to make it smaller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the nav the image is not showed but only the text (en-US)

I really can't see why the image isn't be shown on the nav, but I would suggest to you first check if it's included in the solution, then, inspect with your preffered developer tool what's the Html generated, and if it's properly generated, check the request about that image. If it's successfully requested, then your problem is in CSS.

**Update:**
Ok, I don't know exactly why I didn't see it before, but your images are using the tilde at the start of its path. While it's exactly what you need to specify for Asp.net that the path is absolute, in plain Html paths, it's just a common character, so it's looking for "http://example.com/~/assets/images/ ..." and not in the root of your domain. (There are some browsers/WebServers that can recognize it, but it's not a standard in URLs. Take a look in the most upvoted answer here: [what is the use of "~" tilde in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252471/)  and also here: [use of tilde (~) in asp.net path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077558/)).

Also, It's a best practice to replace the hardcoded url with a Razor Helper like `@Url.Content("~/assets/images/i18n/en-US.png")`. Note that now I used the tilde, because the ASP.Net will translate to the correct absolute path.
*(I assumed that You are using razor because of `@Html.ActionLink`)

> The dropdown is too large and I dont like it. Is there any way to make it smaller?

There is a rule for class "dropdown-menu" (.dropdown-menu), which has the property min-width set to 160px (min-width: 160px;).
So, it's just override this property with a new rule like:

Html:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu UlLanguageMenu" role="menu">
```

In your CSS layout file:

```
ul.dropdown-menu.UlLanguageMenu{
    min-width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok for the CSS, your suggestion worked. Regarding point 1, the image is included the html is correct and the request is good. In the dropdown there's another instance of the same image in fact.

Comment: Hum... To be really honest, your problem is very odd, but, see my updated answer and try to remove the tilde... Let me know the results...

Comment: So @Lorenzo, did you tried to remove the tildes or use the razor helper?  Any news?

Comment: Sorry for the pause. I was involved in another task with higher priority. Anyway your suggestion to remove the tilde also worked perfectly. This sounds very odd to me because the same code in dropdown just works perfectly. Anyway ,thanks very much, it is a solved problem now, would upvote again if had a chance ;)

Comment: Some times I already experienced this odd behaviour. Browser some times keeps the reference of the file name or/and relative path, then even when it don't find the source, it shows the last file that was found. It happened to me with Js and Css files in a project. Changed the location, and browser still include them, even receiving a 404 response.
Anyway, I'm glad I could help you. You're welcome!