# blockUI how to adjust div and show picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-blockui

This is probably a simple question but cannot figure it out. I am using blockui jquery plugin to block the ui during page redirection. Unfortunately, I have two problems regarding that. First one is my picture, it is not going to be opened and second is there is some white bottom style getting attached which i have no idea how to cut off? Please offer your help.

This is how it looks:
[image]

code:

```
function test() {
        //close modal     
        $.ajax({ url: 'wait.php', cache: false });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#details').click(function () {
            $('#myModalTransportDetails').modal('hide');
            $.blockUI({
                message: '<div class="alert alert-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Opening transport images<img src="~/Images/logo/logo3.png" /></div>'
            });
            test();
        });
```

modal window where button is placed for that action:

```
<div id="myModalTransportDetails" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">REGnr</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="orderDetails">

                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4">LP:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control red-stripe" id="label1">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-4 text-left">Arrive date:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control red-stripe" id="label3">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">




                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "GRTE", New With {.id = 1})" class="btn btn-primary" id="details">
                    Show pictures
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-off" data-dismiss="modal"> Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide the markup?

Comment: As for the image, obviously "~/Images/logo/logo3.png" isn't correct. Is there a [tilde](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6252471/145346) in the url for some reason?

Comment: tilde removed - image showing up, only white div left to be corrected. @AdamJeffers what do you mean by markup?

Comment: Markup = Hypertext Markup Language, also known as... HTML ;)

Comment: @AdamJeffers find html modal's window code from where function is called (from modal window). By the way i would much prefer some additional modal alert/window besides alert class i used to be shown instead - if you know how could i do that - that would be much more welcome than $.blockUI to my question :)