# ~ in Laravel 4.2 routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Does anyone what is the tilde (`~`) character supposed to do **in Laravel route definition** (**not** in urls in general)? It might be Laravel 4.2 specific, not sure. Example:

```php
Route::get('~/preview', ['as' => 'site.preview', // closure follows
```

I found this in a legacy code base I'm working with and cannot google it for the life of me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is the use of "~" tilde in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252471/what-is-the-use-of-tilde-in-url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some research, including searching across the codebase for the [Laravel 4.2 routing component](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/tree/4.2). As far as I can tell, the example route you posted is just a normal route. The `~` is simply part of the route, and doesn't have any special meaning or functionality.

I also tested in Laravel 5.8, and the the example URL you posted matches & works correctly:

[image]